# Hackers have created a new scheme to send passwords

Tags: mathematics, cipher, computer-puzzle

> Note: Following puzzle was used in certain competition and every detail of task is virtual (This certain competition is not ongoing).

Hackers have created a new scheme to send passwords. Unfortunately, the only trace to find the passwords is the certain file.

This a is data of the certain file:

```
. 0
. 1
# 2
# 3
# 4
# 5
# 6
# 7
. 8
. 9
. 10
# 11
# 12
# 13
# 14
# 15
# 16
# 17
. 18
. 19
# 20
# 21
. 22
. 23
. 24
. 25
. 26
. 27
# 28
# 29
. 30
# 31
# 32
# 33
# 34
# 35
# 36
# 37
# 38
. 39
. 40
. 41
# 42
# 43
# 44
# 45
# 46
# 47
# 48
. 49
. 50
# 51
# 52
. 53
. 54
. 55
. 56
# 57
# 58
. 0
# 1
# 2
. 3
. 4
. 5
. 6
# 7
# 8
. 9
# 10
# 11
. 12
. 13
. 14
. 15
. 16
# 17
# 18
. 19
# 20
# 21
. 22
. 23
# 24
# 25
. 26
. 27
# 28
# 29
. 30
# 31
# 32
. 33
. 34
. 35
. 36
. 37
# 38
# 39
. 40
# 41
# 42
. 43
. 44
. 45
. 46
. 47
# 48
# 49
. 50
. 51
# 52
# 53
. 54
. 55
# 56
# 57
. 58
. 0
# 1
# 2
. 3
. 4
. 5
. 6
. 7
. 8
. 9
# 10
# 11
. 12
. 13
. 14
. 15
. 16
# 17
# 18
. 19
# 20
# 21
. 22
. 23
# 24
# 25
. 26
. 27
# 28
# 29
. 30
# 31
# 32
. 33
. 34
. 35
. 36
. 37
# 38
# 39
. 40
# 41
# 42
. 43
. 44
. 45
. 46
. 47
# 48
# 49
. 50
. 51
. 52
# 53
# 54
# 55
# 56
. 57
. 58
. 0
# 1
# 2
. 3
. 4
. 5
. 6
. 7
. 8
. 9
# 10
# 11
. 12
. 13
. 14
. 15
. 16
# 17
# 18
. 19
# 20
# 21
. 22
. 23
# 24
# 25
. 26
. 27
# 28
# 29
. 30
# 31
# 32
# 33
# 34
# 35
# 36
# 37
# 38
. 39
. 40
# 41
# 42
. 43
. 44
. 45
. 46
. 47
# 48
# 49
. 50
. 51
. 52
. 53
# 54
# 55
. 56
. 57
. 58
. 0
# 1
# 2
. 3
. 4
. 5
. 6
. 7
. 8
. 9
# 10
# 11
. 12
. 13
. 14
. 15
. 16
# 17
# 18
. 19
# 20
# 21
. 22
. 23
# 24
# 25
. 26
. 27
# 28
# 29
. 30
# 31
# 32
. 33
. 34
. 35
. 36
. 37
# 38
# 39
. 40
# 41
# 42
. 43
. 44
. 45
. 46
. 47
# 48
# 49
. 50
. 51
. 52
. 53
# 54
# 55
. 56
. 57
. 58
. 0
# 1
# 2
. 3
. 4
. 5
. 6
# 7
# 8
. 9
# 10
# 11
. 12
. 13
. 14
. 15
. 16
# 17
# 18
. 19
# 20
# 21
. 22
. 23
# 24
# 25
. 26
. 27
# 28
# 29
. 30
# 31
# 32
. 33
. 34
. 35
. 36
. 37
# 38
# 39
. 40
# 41
# 42
. 43
. 44
. 45
. 46
. 47
# 48
# 49
. 50
. 51
. 52
. 53
# 54
# 55
. 56
. 57
. 58
. 0
. 1
# 2
# 3
# 4
# 5
# 6
# 7
. 8
. 9
. 10
# 11
# 12
# 13
# 14
# 15
# 16
# 17
. 18
. 19
. 20
# 21
# 22
# 23
. 24
. 25
# 26
# 27
# 28
. 29
. 30
# 31
# 32
# 33
# 34
# 35
# 36
# 37
# 38
. 39
. 40
. 41
# 42
# 43
# 44
# 45
# 46
# 47
# 48
. 49
. 50
. 51
. 52
. 53
# 54
# 55
. 56
. 57
. 58
```

Can you solve the scheme and find the password?

Comment: Is the competition still ongoing?

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil No, It has ended approximately two days ago, the time to solve all tasks was 6 hours, and this was in category of harder tasks.

Comment: Could you tell us which competition this is from? "A competition" is not sufficient credit.

Comment: @Deusovi Cyber Cube 2017, Tbilisi, Georgia.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we

> take each block of 59 ./# as a single line

then we get

> `..######...#######..##......##.########...#######..##....##
>  .##....##.##.....##.##..##..##.##.....##.##.....##..##..##.
>  .##.......##.....##.##..##..##.##.....##.##.....##...####..
>  .##.......##.....##.##..##..##.########..##.....##....##...
>  .##.......##.....##.##..##..##.##.....##.##.....##....##...
>  .##....##.##.....##.##..##..##.##.....##.##.....##....##...
>  ..######...#######...###..###..########...#######.....##...`

so it would seem the password is

> COWBOY.

Comment: How is the password , rot13(pbjobl) ? I don't get it.

Comment: Please refrain from putting the answer in plaintext in your comments. (I've edited your comment to ROT13 it.)

Comment: Perhaps rot13(lbhe oebjfre qbrfa'g eraqre zbabfcnprq sbagf pbeerpgyl)...