# Hackers have created a new scheme to send passwords (advanced version)

Tags: cipher, computer-puzzle

> Note: Following puzzle is an advanced version of this [puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/56443/hackers-have-created-a-new-scheme-to-send-passwords). Both of them were used in a competition called Cyber Cube 2017 located in Tbilisi, Georgia. Every detail of task is virtual and this competition has ended before any of it's puzzles were posted on this website.

Hackers have improved the previous scheme and used it as their current method to exchange passwords, It's only trace is the following file:

```
.
# 
#
.
.
.
.
#
#
.
#
#
#
#
.
#
#
.
.
.
.
#
#
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
#
#
.
.
.
.
#
#
#
.
.
.
.
#
#
#
.
.
.
#
#
.
.
#
#
.
.
#
#
#
.
.
.
#
#
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
#
#
.
.
.
#
#
.
#
#
.
.
.
#
#
#
#
.
.
#
#
.
.
#
#
.
.
#
#
#
#
.
.
#
#
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
#
#
.
.
#
#
.
.
.
#
#
.
.
#
#
.
#
#
.
#
#
.
.
#
#
.
.
#
#
.
#
#
.
#
#
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
#
#
.
#
#
.
.
.
.
.
#
#
.
#
#
.
.
#
#
#
#
.
.
#
#
.
.
#
#
.
.
#
#
#
#
.
#
#
.
.
.
.
#
#
.
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
.
#
#
.
.
.
#
#
#
.
.
#
#
.
.
#
#
.
.
.
#
#
#
.
#
#
.
.
.
.
#
#
.
#
#
.
.
.
.
.
#
#
.
#
#
.
.
.
.
#
#
.
#
#
#
#
.
#
#
.
.
.
.
#
#
.
.
#
#
#
#
#
#
.
.
#
#
.
.
.
.
.
#
#
```

Can you decipher data of the file to obtain exchanged information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is

> ninja

since if you

> rearrange it by putting it in 7 row, it will show:
>
>
>  `.##....##.####.##....##.......##....###...
>  .###...##..##..###...##.......##...##.##..
>  .####..##..##..####..##.......##..##...##.
>  .##.##.##..##..##.##.##.......##.##.....##
>  .##..####..##..##..####.##....##.#########
>  .##...###..##..##...###.##....##.##.....##
>  .##....##.####.##....##..######..##.....##`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, could you please explain how you found out that data must've been rearranged in 7 rows?

Comment: I read the previous puzzle you posted(with solution), and experimented if i can rearrange it to x rows so there will be something visible

Comment: So you basically used a brute force method which currently seems to be the only method. Thanks a lot again!

Comment: @ShellRox its not really a full brute force, you first assume the split will form an even number of lines. There are 294 lines total so it must be a factor of this. The factors are 1,2,3,6,7,14,21,42,49,98,147,294,. We can get rid of 98 and above since this is coding related and there is a weird convention regarding 80 char widths from the old days. at this time it is brute force going down and you can get it on your second try (width 42)

Comment: Also the other puzzle had 7 rows as well.

Comment: @IPlant Oh i see why i got 42 as a width, I was wondering if there was some connection. By the way could you name the weird convection that happens after width of 98? Thanks a lot.